# Where is "C" wire on Honeywell 8043F1036

Tags: wiring, hvac, nest

My home is 3 zones (2 hot water, 1 steam) and heated with oil. I added a Nest Thermostat E to one of the zones and while it does work without the 'C' wire, I would like to wire it anyways so my relay stops buzzing when the Nest is powering itself. All of my thermostat wires have 3 conductors and since I have no air conditioning here, I believe I can use the unused 'Y' conductor.

I have 2 zone relay valves (Honeywell 8043F1036) and I'm not certain where the common wire is on this relay.

[image]

I believe it is either wires 1 or 2 labeled in the picture. The wiring diagrams on Honeywells website aren't clear which terminal is common, or if it is even one of these terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiring diagram I found, typical wiring is as follows.

[image: Honeywell 8043F1036 Wiring]

- 1 END SWITCH (To circulator or another valve)
- 2 END SWITCH (To circulator or another valve)
- 3 TH/TR (Thermostat and Transformer)
- 4 TH (Thermostat)
- 5 TR (Transformer)

You'll have to verify this is how *your* valve is wired, but it looks just like the diagram to me. If this *is* how it's wired, you should be able to connect the `c` wire to the `TR` (5 in your image) terminal on the valve.

Comment: My system was wired exactly as you mentioned. The two thermostat wires were wired backwards in my old thermostat. This didn't matter for a simple mercury switch unit, but I had to reverse the R & Y wires on the Nest to get it working correctly. Working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Every transformer has 2 terminals on the 24V side.

One of the terminals is R, and that already goes to the thermostat.

The other transformer terminal must necessarily be C.